Coin Change Recursive, memoization gone wrong
I'm trying to understand why first one fails and second works, all I'm doing is passing along coinTrack, call it redundant but why does it not work?
It works without memoization, but on using memoization it fails, so something's wrong there
The Input it fails on
coins = {1, 2, 5} target = 11
solve returns 7 => Incorrect
solver returns 3 => correct
Local Output
Ans=7
Ans=3

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

map<pair<int, int>, int> dp;

// Returns incorrect solution - 7
int solve(vector<int> coins, int index, int result, int coinTrack) {
    if(result==0) {
        return coinTrack;
    }

    if(result<0)
        return INT_MAX;

    if(index==coins.size())
        return INT_MAX;

    if(dp.count({index, result}))
        return dp[{index, result}];

    int keepPicking = solve(coins, index, result-coins[index], coinTrack+1);
    int pick = solve(coins, index+1, result-coins[index], coinTrack+1);
    int skip = solve(coins, index+1, result, coinTrack);    

    return dp[{index, result}] = min(keepPicking, min(pick, skip));
}

// Returns correct solution - 3
int solver(vector<int> coins, int index, int result) {
    if(result==0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if(result<0)
        return INT_MAX;

    if(index==coins.size())
        return INT_MAX;

    if(dp.count({index, result}))
        return dp[{index, result}];

    int keepPicking = solver(coins, index, result-coins[index]);
    int pick = solver(coins, index+1, result-coins[index]);
    int skip = solver(coins, index+1, result);    

    if(keepPicking!=INT_MAX)
        keepPicking++;
    if(pick!=INT_MAX)
        pick++;
    
    return dp[{index, result}] = min(keepPicking, min(pick, skip));
}

int main() {
    
    vector<int> coins = {1, 2, 5};
    cout<<"Ans="<<solve(coins, 0, 11, 0)<<"\n";
    dp.clear();
    cout<<"Ans="<<solver(coins, 0, 11)<<"\n";
    return 0;
}


@463035818_is_not_an_ai Do you see this under the question? The Input it fails on coins = {1, 2, 5} target = 11
Function-1 returns 7 Function-2 returns 3 => correct
Function-1 (Incorrect)

@user2643191 A question such as this should include a [mre] (aka SSCCE). That is; a complete and minimal program that we can simply copy'n'paste into a file, compile and run and reproduce your issue.

It seems to be a common misconception, but debugging isnt a magic skill exercised by arcane code-wizards staring at fragments of code ;). It takes the actual code, tests, and a debugger then really anybody can find a bug.

I will give debugging another shot, I have updated the post

Either of the two versions has the same memoization. But you shouldnt make them both use the same map for that. You shouldnt use globals in the first place.

well ok. you clear the map inbetween. Nevertheless, this is how hard to read code is written.

also not the issue, but you shouldnt pass the coins vector by value on every call.

Agree, why waste time on copying when we can pass by reference.

the differences are I) You return coinTrack instead of 0 when result == 0 and II) the block incrementing pick and keepPicking is missing. I do not understand why in the presence of this changes you expect the two versions to yield the same result (and when you change it so that both return 0 when result == 0 and both increment pick and keepPicking then of course they yield the same result). What was the idea when you added coinPick ? The question boils down to explaining why you expectation is false, but for that you need to tell us why you expect the same result from them

of course I might be just too silly to see it, but obvious it is not. My point is that its up to you to explain.

I) when result becomes zero in the first function, until that point coinTrack is tracking number of coins we used, so we return it.
The other function I'm doing 1 + recursion() instead of recursion(x+1)
II) It is missing because I increased coinTrack in the call prior to that and sent it for recursion, I'll add comments to the code too

@user2643191 -- Why not do the obvious debugging by issuing cout calls to strategic spots in each function, and then compare the differences?  You shouldn't be waiting until the very end of the functions to discover the wrong value(s) were produced.

you could go even one step further and pass along a vector of coins that have been picked so far rather than only their count.

another tip is to draw the call graph with pen and paper. The input is small enough so that is possible. That accompanied by using a debugger (or the suggested cout debugging) would also help to spot the issue

recursion gets messy due to unlimited supply of coins, since one of the choices of three is to keep picking the same coin, but I'll try and update if I figure out

I once wrote a general explanation here on SO, see if it helps. :)
